# How to decode in python when encoded using CodeIgniter's encode?

Tags: python-2.7, codeigniter-2

I store userNames, passwords and security-tokens using CodeIgniter's encode method like -

```
$this->load->library('encrypt');
//...
$password = $this->encrypt->encode($rows["password"]);
//Then save it in password column of user_credentials table.
```

Now, In python, I want to decode this encoded password. I have been trying to decode it with python's [hashlib](http://docs.python.org/2/library/hashlib.html), but I am not able to.

I think it is because CI's encrypt library does more than md5 on the password-

```
function encode($string, $key = '')
{
    $key = $this->get_key($key);
    if ($this->_mcrypt_exists === TRUE)
    {
        $enc = $this->mcrypt_encode($string, $key);
    }
    else
    {
        $enc = $this->_xor_encode($string, $key);
    }
    return base64_encode($enc);
}

function decode($string, $key = '')
{
    $key = $this->get_key($key);

    if (preg_match('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\/\+=]/', $string))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    $dec = base64_decode($string);

    if ($this->_mcrypt_exists === TRUE)
    {
        if (($dec = $this->mcrypt_decode($dec, $key)) === FALSE)
        {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $dec = $this->_xor_decode($dec, $key);
    }

    return $dec;
}
```

How should I decode it? I need to write above decode function in python. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at CI's system/libraries/Encrypt.php and check out how mcrypt_decode and _remove_cipher_noise work. There's a python interface to the mcrypt library [available](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-mcrypt). Good hunting.

Comment: Hi, Installed this library from the link you gave me. When I do `import mcrypt` in python prompt it says the `mcrypt` module is not available. I am lost.

Comment: Hi, I have started to write decode in python from decode of CI. What is python equivalent to CI's `_xor_decode` . Please help. I am about to call it done.

Comment: Check your PYTHONPATH to make sure Python can find the module. You may need to install libmcrypt as well. [Here's some ports](http://mcrypt.hellug.gr/lib/index.html)

Comment: BTW, from the [CI docs](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/encryption.html): "The Encryption Class provides two-way data encryption. It uses a scheme that either compiles the message using a randomly hashed bitwise XOR encoding scheme, or is encrypted using the Mcrypt library. If Mcrypt is not available on your server the encoded message will still provide a reasonable degree of security for encrypted sessions or other such "light" purposes. If Mcrypt is available, you'll be provided with a high degree of security appropriate for storage." So best to go with mcrypt if you can

Comment: Hi, `$this->_mcrypt_exists = FALSE` . So In python I only have to do the xor part. So I need a method equivalent to `_xor_decode` from php. I have written python decode method till this point and searching for xor. Do you know such method?

Comment: Ah, that means no mcrypt support with PHP - it's not too hard to install, [here's](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mcrypt.installation.php) the php.net docs